# Q:Controller present 2 second , how to make it looks like only one transition?

Tags: ios, launch, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a requirement, `Controller1` present to -> `Controller2` -> present to `Controller3`, how to make it looks like `Controller1` present to -> `Controller3`?

You know the requirement is when I start my `app`, it will first in `LaunchController` then `LoginController`, and at last it present to `MainController`,but when I second time to start my app, it looks like from `LaunchController` present to `MainController`, because I saved the `username` and `password` in my `sandbox`.
How to realize the function?

Comment: on launching the second time, when you have the username & pasword saved, you can directly create the MainController and set it as the rootviewcontroller to your application window. did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the rootviewcontroller of your application window to your MainController directly the second time; when you have username & password. Something like this:

```
if(username && password)
        [self.window setRootViewController:[[MainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainController" bundle:nil]];
```

You can do this inside

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: I know this method, but there is a question is that, when I `logout` of my `application`, I want to dismiss to `LoginController`, not to `LaunchController`.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? im confused what you want to achieve. You should use a navigation controller to 'push' view controllers instead of presenting several view controllers. Then on logout you can just do [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you, when I 2th start my `app`, there I have password and username, so after show `LaunchViewContrller`, I will present (or) push to `MainViewController`, so I login to my app, if I want to logout, I will dissmiss(or pop) to `LoginController` this is reasonable, but  because when I 2th login was from `lauchVioewController` to `mainviewController`, so the `stack ` is have no `LoginViewController`, I will logout to` LaunchViewController`, how to resolve this ?

Comment: ok, what you can do is get the navigation controller's viewControllers property, its an array. From that array, remove or replace the object at index 0, which will be your launch view controller with a new instance of LoginViewController. Then set the viewcontrollers back to navigation controller :)

Comment: something like this: ```NSMutableArray *navViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    [navViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil]]; // assuming the root view controller at index '0' is the LaunchViewController
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:navViewControllers];```